# What is the difference between corAR1 and corCAR1 correlation structures?

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I'm fitting a mixed multilevel model in R using the [nlme](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html) package, and I don't understand what is the difference between the covariance structures `corAR1` and `corCAR1`. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you checked any of the references mentioned in the help files of the two functions?

Comment: As a hint/amplification/followup of @RomanLuštrik's comment: see Pinheiro and Bates 2000; you can see relevant bits on Google Books (pp. 236, 243-244).  This is basically the "what have you tried" comment  ( http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ ).  If you give us a more specific starting point than "I don't understand" (and show evidence of effort), it will be easier/more rewarding to help ...

Answer (score 8):

Adding an answer because this question was never directly answered and I came here looking for the answer. Looking at the NLME documentation, `corAR1` represents an autocorrelation structure of order 1. The `corCAR1` argument represents an autocorrelation structure of order 1, with a continuous time covariate. In addition, Singer and Willet (2003) note the important distinction is that `corCAR1` allows for unequally spaced time covariates or observations, while corAR1 requires equally spaced time intervals.

Comment: You may also need to use `corCAR1` in the case of missing data, which could cause equally spaced time to become unequally spaced.